# How to merge 2 object laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Im getting data from `table` A with `first()` function and did the same with `table B` , i need to pass a variable to `blade` which contain data from both tables , how can i do it ?

I've tried `merge()` function but i cant do it.

```php
public function index(){
    $mahasiswa= mahasiswa::where('npm',Session::get('npm'))->first();

    if($mahasiswa->Agama=="Islam"){
        $agama=agama_islam::where('npm',Session::get('npm'))->first();
    }
    else if($mahasiswa->Agama=="Kristen Protestan"){
        $agama=agama_kristen::where('npm',Session::get('npm'))->first();
    }
    else if($mahasiswa->Agama=="Kristen Katolik"){
        $agama=agama_katolik::where('npm',Session::get('npm'))->first();
    }
    else if($mahasiswa->Agama=="Hindu"){
        $agama=agama_hindu::where('npm',Session::get('npm'))->first();
    }
    else if($mahasiswa->Agama=="Buddha"){
        $agama=agama_buddha::where('npm',Session::get('npm'))->first();
    }

    if($agama==NULL){
        return view('biodata',['mahasiswa'=>$mahasiswa]);
    }else{
        $mahasiswamerge=$mahasiswa->merge($agama);
        return view('biodata',['mahasiswa'=>$mahasiswamerge]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **push** instead of **merge**. If there is same id on both object one will overwrite the other. Try

```
$mahasiswamerge = collect();
$mahasiswamerge->push($mahasiswa);
$mahasiswamerge->push($agama);
return view('biodata',['mahasiswa'=>$mahasiswamerge]);
```